# Поворот при соприкосновении

Tags: разработка-игр, unity3d

Всем привет.
Есть платформа, на ней висит rigidbody и boxcollider. На платформе стоит игрок, на нем висит то же самое, и используется гравитация. Игрок поворачивается следующим методом:

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation,angle,Time.deltaTime*speedRotation);
```

когда transform.rotation = angle, объект начинает "дергаться", то есть поворачиваться вдоль Z в разные стороны где то на 1 градус. Когда он поднимается, или я отключаю гравитацию, "дергания" прекращаются. Пробовал добавить физ. материал с трением = 0, не помогает. Как быть?

Answer (score 1):

RotateTowards в даном случае поворачивает обьект и трение все равно происходит.

Подозреваю что этого эфекта не будет если использовать плавное изменения простого Rotate много раз подряд с небольшим сдвигом.

Для этого очень удобно использовать библиотеку LeanTween.

Выйдет что то вроде LeanTween.RotateByX(gameObject, -100, 1f);

так же там возможно использовать некие физические затухания поворота используя в конце выше показанного метода .SetEase( someEase);